# Bounding sum of RV with high Probability

Tags: probability, inequality, expected-value, stochastic-calculus, moment-problem

Let $X_i$ real random variables for $i \in 1, \dots n$ such that
$$
\mathbb{P}\left(\|X_i\|\geq \frac{1}{n}\log\left(\frac{1}{\delta}\right) \right)\leq\delta
$$

Is there a chance to find a constant $c>0$ independent of $n$ and $\delta$ such that

$$
\mathbb{P}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\|X_i\|\geq \log\left(\frac{c}{\delta}\right) \right)\leq\delta?
$$
Or does anyone know  similar bound for this problem?

---

What i tried so far was using that
$$
\mathbb{P}\left(\|X_i\|\geq \frac{1}{n}\log\left(\frac{1}{\delta}\right) \right)\leq\delta
$$
implies a bound for moments (using the layer cake inequality) so we have
$$
\mathbb{E}[\|X_i\|^q] \leq \frac{C^q}{n^q}.
$$
From this i wanted to use markov ineq. :
$$
\mathbb{P}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\|X_i\|\geq \log\left(\frac{c}{\delta}\right) \right)\leq\frac{c}{\delta}\mathbb{E}[\exp(\sum_{i=1}^n\|X_i\|)].
$$
and then use the expansion of the exponential function...
However i can not assume that the variables are independent so i don't know how to pull the sum out of the expectation. Any suggestions are verry appreciated.